# List count changes in between numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, search

There is strange issue with TableView. My App is crashing because noOfRow count is different from cellForRow calling times. All is working perfectly in between that, sometimes something happens and I debug it and found that the list by using which I send no of rows count in tableView-datasource is changes while calling cellForRow.

For Ex:-

If noOfRows is 14 with same list, then

cellForRow gets only 4 rows with that list.

Code Snippet is given below. I have added logs to debug.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.isSearchOn) {
        NSLog(@"search number of rows: %d",[[self.searchMap allKeys] count]);
        return [[self.searchMap allKeys] count];
    }
    NSLog(@"map number of rows: %d",[[self.drugsMap allKeys] count]);
    return [[self.drugsMap allKeys] count] + 1; //1 for footer cell.
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (!self.isSearchOn && indexPath.row == [[self.drugsMap allKeys] count]) {
        return self.footerCell;
    }

    MCIPDrugCell *drugCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[MCIPDrugCell cellIdentifier]];

    if(drugCell == nil)
        drugCell = [MCIPDrugCell newInstance];

    drugCell.parentController = self;
    drugCell.delegate = self;
    drugCell.handler = self.handler;
    drugCell.currentIndex = self.selectedGeneric;

    NSArray *keys = (self.isSearchOn)?[[self.searchMap allKeys] sortedList]:[[self.drugsMap allKeys] sortedList];

    NSLog(@"searchOn %d\n keys: %@",self.isSearchOn, keys);

    NSString *genericName = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *brandsByGeneric = (self.isSearchOn)?[self.searchMap objectForKey:genericName]:[self.drugsMap objectForKey:genericName];

    drugCell = [MCIPDrugCell configureDrugCell:drugCell genericName:genericName withDrugList:brandsByGeneric forIndex:indexPath.row withSelectedIndex:self.selectedGeneric];

    drugCell.btnInfo.tag = indexPath.row;
    [drugCell.btnInfo addTarget:self action:@selector(moveInstruction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    drugCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return drugCell;
}
```

Debug Logs are given below:-

```
2017-03-03 16:06:54.484 mCura[12934:1098450] search number of rows: 14

2017-03-03 16:06:54.536 mCura[12934:1098450] searchOn 1
 keys: (
    "#",
    Cardace,
    Ramipril,
    "Ramipril + Hydrochlorthiazide"
)
2017-03-03 16:06:54.544 mCura[12934:1098450] searchOn 1
 keys: (
    "#",
    Cardace,
    Ramipril,
    "Ramipril + Hydrochlorthiazide"
)
2017-03-03 16:06:54.552 mCura[12934:1098450] searchOn 1
 keys: (
    "#",
    Cardace,
    Ramipril,
    "Ramipril + Hydrochlorthiazide"
)
2017-03-03 16:06:54.560 mCura[12934:1098450] searchOn 1
 keys: (
    "#",
    Cardace,
    Ramipril,
    "Ramipril + Hydrochlorthiazide"
)
2017-03-03 16:06:54.568 mCura[12934:1098450] searchOn 1
 keys: (
    "#",
    Cardace,
    Ramipril,
    "Ramipril + Hydrochlorthiazide"
)
```

On **Fifth** calling of cellForRow it crashes because [self.searchMap allKeys] count has been changed to 4 as you see keys are printed in logs. How can I overcome this problem.

As request by @CodeChanger configureDrugCell

```
+(MCIPDrugCell *)configureDrugCell:(MCIPDrugCell *)cell
                       genericName:(NSString *)genericName
                      withDrugList:(NSArray *)drugList
                          forIndex:(NSInteger)index
                 withSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)selectedIndex {

    cell.currentIndex = selectedIndex;
    cell.btnGenericName.tag = index;
    cell.btnwriteprescription.tag = index;
    cell.collectionView.tag = index;
    cell.genericIndex = index;

    cell.genericArray = [drugList mutableCopy];

    [cell.btnGenericName setTitle:genericName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.collectionView reloadData];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You do not handle the `+ 1` footer in `cellForRow...`, so `[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` crashes.

Comment: please read post carefully `+ 1` is for normal list. And I am having problem with search ON.

Comment: Where is your search condition in cellForRowAtIndexPath ??

Comment: Also Post your `configureDrugCell` method I thing something wrong over there ?

Comment: Ah, sorry. My bad. Is it possible that `isSearchOn` changes state in between calls to `numberOfRows...` and `cellForRowAt...`?

Comment: It's not clear why the row count is 14. What is the structure of `self.searchMap`? It's an `NSDictionary` from what to what?

Comment: @CodeChanger NSArray *keys = (self.isSearchOn)?[[self.searchMap allKeys] sortedList]:[[self.drugsMap allKeys] sortedList];

Comment: As I mention in my comment please post your `configureDrugCell` method something wrong over there.

Comment: configureDrugCell method is used just to set values to particular cell, nothing else.

Comment: OK so here you haven't added search condition like ` (self.isSearchOn)?` any reason why you have not added condition ?

Comment: u r not reading code properly buddy or u don't understand what going on there. Why should I need to apply isSearchOn condition if I already picked up object by that condition and passed to configureCell. If you are not able to understand don't do it.  Check these lines       NSString *genericName = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *brandsByGeneric = (self.isSearchOn)?[self.searchMap objectForKey:genericName]:[self.drugsMap objectForKey:genericName];